# How to convert a list into a csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to write csv file from a list:

list:

```
newest = ['x11;y11;z11', 'x12;y12;z12', 'x13;y13;z13', 'x14;y14;z14', 'x15;y15;z15', 'x16;y16;z16', 'x17;y17;z17', 'x18;y18;z18', 'x19;y19;z19', 'x20;y20;z20']
```

My actual code:

```
with open(r'listtocsv.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=';')
    wr.writerow(newest)
```

My actual result:

[image: ActualResult]

Result wanted:

[image: ResultWanted]

Comment: can you use pandas?

Comment: The csv module inserts delimiters into the lines as it writes them. If your values are already ;-separated, you could just write them as plain text to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv    
newest = ['x11;y11;z11', 'x12;y12;z12', 'x13;y13;z13', 'x14;y14;z14', 'x15;y15;z15', 'x16;y16;z16', 'x17;y17;z17', 'x18;y18;z18', 'x19;y19;z19', 'x20;y20;z20']

new = []
for i in newest:
    new.append(i.split(";"))

with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerows(new)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: It's working! Thank you @Tal